# docker service update: "image could not be accessed on a registry to record it's digest"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm

I have an image on Amazon's Elastic Container Registry (ECR) that I want to deploy as a Docker service in my Docker single-node swarm. Currently the service is running an older version of the image's `latest` tag, but I've since uploaded a newer version of the `latest` tag to ECR.

Running `docker service update --force my_service` on my swarm node, which uses image `XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my_service:latest`, results in:

> image XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my_service:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record its digest. Each node will access XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my_service:latest independently,
>   possibly leading to different nodes running different versions of the image.

This appears to prevent the node from pulling a new copy of the `latest` tag from the registry, and the service from properly updating.

I'm properly logged in with `docker login` to ECR, and running `docker pull XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my_service:latest` works fine (and returns a digest).

Why is `docker service update` unable to read the digest from the ECR registry despite the image being available?

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error when running: "docker service update --with-registry-auth --image example.com/group/myimage:X.Y.Z mystack_myservice".

I run docker 17.05.

I've logged into the gitlab container registry before running the command as well (on the manager node) so it should not have any problem accessing the registry.

The error: "Error: image example.com/group/myimage:X.Y.Z could not be accessed on a registry to record its digest."

Comment: My problem turned out to be that I was using the wrong image tag (the version part). As long as I'm logged in and use the --with-registry-auth argument it works.

Answer (score 68):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by using `--with-registry-auth`.
After you logged in with `docker login`, can you confirm the same update command with `--with-registry-auth`?

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34153#issuecomment-316047924

Comment: Solved it for me... Thanks.